# Why does the newsletter come doubled?

Tags: support

As you can see, I receive two identical newsletter e-mails at a time:

[image]

I've been subscribed for two weeks, and both times I got two identical e-mails.

Comment: I'm guessing is a side effect of this fix [I just received my Stack Overflow Weekly Newsletter, and the "Top new questions this week" are a bunch of low vote, low activity questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275551)